# View активности отображаются поверх DrawerLayouta [closed]

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

При выдвижении DrawerLayout кнопки отображаются поверх меню:Кнопки отображаются на поле Выдвижной Панели. Спасибо заранее!

Вот как выглядит окно приложения:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBW35.png

MainActivity.java:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main_activity.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@layout/menu_nav" >

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:text="BUTTON1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="BUTTON2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

nav_header.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/unnamed" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

menu_nav.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_time"
            android:title="Point1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_time"
            android:title="Point2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_time"
            android:title="Point2" />

    </group>
    <item android:title="Others">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_extra1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_time"
                android:title="Extra1"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_extra2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_time"
                android:title="Extra2" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Собственно они так и должны отображаться... Если хотите, чтобы отображались внутри перекрываемой разметки - поместите их туда. Те. в LinearLayout, который содержит Toolbar

Comment: Т.е. иначе никак? Редактировать разметку исходя из положения в LinearLayout?

Comment: Да, только так. Конечно, вам не обязательно LinearLayot там использовать. Можно также ConstraintLayout